# Update Price massively in magento

Tags: mysql, magento

I need to update the price of all products in some categories by 10%.
The problem is that I must round it to the .99 cent

If the price is 120*0.90= 118.8, but I must put 118.99

EDIT:  I forgot to mention, some of my products have tier pricing, so the tier prices also need to be lowered by 10%

EDIT:

The following code updates the price, by 10%, however I dont know how to round to .99. and the most difficult part is how can I do it with tier pricing>??

```
update catalog_product_entity_decimal
  set value = value*0.9
  where attribute_id = 64 and
        entity_in (select product_id from catalog_category_product
                    where category_id = X);
```

Anyone knows how to make a query for this? I am not a big fan of mysql :)

thank you

Comment: @whoever , paste a commment of why you want to close, is it duplicated? no I didnt find it?  Is it too broad? no Its not! its very specific? isnt it a programming question? yes it is!!

Comment: Luis, your question belongs to a class of problems we call `I can haz teh codez`. That is it is a request from someone that we write code to solve a problem that is only specified in general terms. The OP (i.e. **you**) does not show any code to demonstrate what he/she has tried. This reduces us to a -rent-a-coder- except nobody gets paid. That is exactly the reason it was voted `not constructive` because we are not your code slaves. So -1 and voting to close. (will reverse the -1 if you can produce some code).

Comment: lol, I have seen worst questions here with +50s, but I pasted the code I know for your pleasure. :), you still havent - vote for close.

Comment: So, @Luis, if the price goes to `110.00`, it should be rounded up to `110.99` ?

Comment: Not sure if it's because I'm on an old versio of Magento, but the attribute_id of 64 is the cost not price.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure that the prices itself have to be changed? You could just as well do with a rebate of 10% to all customers (logged in and not logged in equally), and the outcome would be exactly the same, and you save yourself the hassle of changing all the prices, because there's not automated way to do that.

The best ways to do it would be a short php script (because the product export/import does not support tier prices) or an external application that supports magento as a data source and target.

Comment: thats a solution I also thought, but the customer wont see the price on the frontend, they will see the price after they add the item to the cart. you are talking about shopping cart rules, right?

Comment: There are shopping cart rules as well as catalog rules. A shopping cart rule is what you describe, however, a catalog price rule is applied automatically to all displayed prices as long as the user is in an eligible group.

Comment: I like this solution, also, let me try it.

Comment: but with this one, I cant round the price to .99, or is it possible? I am on the editor of the rules and I cant see how could I do that.

Comment: My company is in the process of writing an application that docks onto any magento store, be it a new one or one that has been running before. It can then pull the while catalog structure out of the application, supply you with a nice web interface where you can batch-alter your products in any imaginable way (any that a user story has been written for, at least), then dump the data back in. We know that external tools for magento are necessary as hell, and we're delivering. So we know your pain.

Comment: You're right, my suggestion is noit capable of automagically rounding to anything. I'm sorry.

Comment: I still find this the easier one, because my boss wanted the 10% Off, for 3 weeks only, and I think its safer this way.

Answer (score 3):

You can update the price catalog:

See @ypercube's answer

Or you can just use a select to apply the discount

```
SELECT CIEL((cpe.value * 0.9)  + 0.01) - 0.01 as Discounted_price
FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal cpe
WHERE cpe.attribute_id = 64 
  AND cpe.entity IN (SELECT ccp.product_id FROM catalog_category_product ccp
                WHERE ccp.category_id = 'X');
```

Let me move away from your code:

**Tier pricing**

```
SELECT 
  b.product_id
  ,pr.name
  ,CIEL((p.price * d.percentage) + 0.01) - 0.01 as discounted_price
FROM basket b
INNER JOIN product pr ON (b.product_id = pr.id)
INNER JOIN price p ON (p.product_id = pr.id 
                  AND b.sale_date BETWEEN p.valid_from AND p.valid_till) 
INNER JOIN discount d ON (pr.productcat = d.productcat
                      AND b.quantity BETWEEN d.min_cty AND d.max_qty
                      AND b.sale_date BETWEEN d.valid_from AND d.valid_till) 
WHERE b.transaction_nr = '12457';
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling

Comment: wow, i would never been able to figure it out, I am sure this will help me also!!!.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `CEILING()` function, then substract `0.01`:

```
update catalog_product_entity_decimal
  set value = CEILING(value*0.9 +0.01) - 0.01 
  where attribute_id = 64 and
        entity_in (select product_id from catalog_category_product
                    where category_id = X);
```

or:

```
update catalog_product_entity_decimal
  set value = CEILING(value*0.9) - 0.01 
  where attribute_id = 64 and
        entity_in (select product_id from catalog_category_product
                    where category_id = X);
```

First version will round the (values*0.9), if between `100.99001` and `101.00`, to `101.99`, while the second will round them to `100.99`.

And really, be sure to run **this only once**.

It would also be wise to take a backup of the table or at least the (`where attribute_id = 64`) part or make a copy of the current catalog prices in another table.

Comment: what about for the tier pricing? lets suppose I have an item at 100, but I sell 3 at 95, 5 at 90 and 10, at 85.   the discount needs to apply also to this tier pricing.  Do I need to make some extra query for this?

Comment: @Luis: either update your question, or post a new one. One needs to know the tables structure and how they are realted for this.